# Setting High Availability Infrastructure

Tags: azure, microservices, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

[Problem Statement]
We have a Tier 0 service which has haproxy LB and multiple back end server  configured behind it. Currently, infrastructure is serving P99 with ~100 ms. Now, as per the 100% availability and 0 downtime. Sometimes we see, some of the back end servers misbehaves or goes out of LB and that moment all of landed requests on those back end servers gets timeout.
So we looking to have configuration like that if any request on server takes more than 100ms then this same request can route to another back end server and we can achieve the ~100℅ no time outs.

[Disclaimer]
I understand after a certain retires if still request timeout, then it will serve the timeouts to end consumer of our Tier - 0 service.

[Tech Stack]
HAProxy
Java
Java
MySQL
Azure

Would appreciate to discuss on this problem as I searched a lot but didn't get any reference, the way I am thinking but yes this could be possible by other ways so that we can achieve the no downtime and under the defined SLA of service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `option redispatch` directive sends a request to a different server.
The `retry-on` directive states what type of errors to retry on.
The `retries` directive states how many times to retry.

```
option redispatch 1
retry-on all-retryable-errors
retries 3
```

Plus, you'll want to test how to setup the timeouts for the following

```
timeout connect 5000ms
timeout client 50000ms
timeout server 50000ms
```

Make sure all requests are idempotent and have no side effects. Otherwise, you will end up causing a lot of problems for yourself.

Comment: Daniel Cazares yes all of the landing requests will be GET calls only, so there is no question of being idempotent. Let me try it out, but I think this would be the right answer for this. Do you think, we can do something else here.

Comment: Try it out, see if it works and let me know. Interested to hear the results.